# TextBlock and Image inside Dockpanel

Tags: wpf, xaml, dockpanel

I have the below code.  I am trying to place the image directly to the right of the textblock within the border, but the image is almost touching the right side of the screen.  How can I allign the image to the right of the textblock

```
<Border BorderBrush="#FFD6D4D4" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"
        Height="28" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="#FFF7F7F7"
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                <DockPanel LastChildFill="False">
                    <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Left" 
                               Style="{StaticResource HeaderTextBlockStyle}" 
                               Text="Check new items"
                               VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="2" />
                    <Image
                       DockPanel.Dock="Left"
                       VerticalAlignment="Center"                      
                       SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                       UseLayoutRounding="True"
                       RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality"
                       Source="/Media/pointer.png"
                       RenderTransformOrigin="0.95,4.046" 
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0"  
                       Height="25.306" Width="25.008>
                        <Image.RenderTransform>
                            <TransformGroup>
                                <ScaleTransform/>
                                <SkewTransform/>
                                <RotateTransform Angle="49.57"/>
                                <TranslateTransform X="-39.746" Y="-21.185"/>
                            </TransformGroup>
                        </Image.RenderTransform>
                    </Image>                  
                </DockPanel>
            </Border>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   Try using the Grid control and define two columns into it

    <Border BorderBrush="#FFD6D4D4" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"
            Height="28" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="#FFF7F7F7"
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <Grid>
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
     <Column Definition Width="*"/>
     <Column Definition Width="*"/>
 </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0"                                   Style="{StaticResource HeaderTextBlockStyle}" 
                                   Text="Check new items"
                                   VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="2" />
                        <Image
                           Grid.Column="1"                               VerticalAlignment="Center"                      
                           SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                           UseLayoutRounding="True"
                           RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality"
                           Source="/Media/pointer.png"
                           RenderTransformOrigin="0.95,4.046" 
                           HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0"  
                           Height="25.306" Width="25.008>
                            <Image.RenderTransform>
                                <TransformGroup>
                                    <ScaleTransform/>
                                    <SkewTransform/>
                                    <RotateTransform Angle="49.57"/>
                                    <TranslateTransform X="-39.746" Y="-21.185"/>
                                </TransformGroup>
                            </Image.RenderTransform>
                        </Image>                  
                    </Grid>
            </Border>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using a StackPanel with Orientation set to horizontal instead of the dockpanel. That should put the image right next to the textblock.

Answer (score 1):

if you still want to use the dock panel try setting the margin you want, on the image like margin="0,0,100,0"